# Python function not printing - only storing

Tags: python, function

Please look at this code below. It should be clear that I want t print out a list however python is only storing the list and not printing it. How do I fix this?

```
import numpy as np

sumy = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


def sumymoment():
    for k in range(1,7,1):
        return [np.mean([i**k for i in sumy[2:]])]

print sumymoment
```

Returns as:

```
<function sumymoment at 0x000000000B0AE5F8>
```

Comment: You have to call a function if you want it to be called. `print sumymoment()`

Comment: `sumymoment` is an object.

Comment: Note that when you call sumymoment() it will return a list containing a single mean - the one computed with k=1. Do you want it to return a list containing all 6 means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to call it as

```
print sumymoment()
```

Note:

If Py3, then

```
print(sumymoment())
```

Comment: yup printing out the memory address of the function and not the result